Display 1 decimal point but round up if the second decimal is 5 or above
I want to display only 1 decimal number and round it to the closest first decimal, but if the second decimal is 5 or above, round up and not down.
For example:
16.55 > 16.6
5.42 > 5.4
23.88 > 23.9

I tried the following:
SELECT ROUND(time, 1, 1) as time

And it mostly works, except for when the second decimal number is 5 and then it rounds it down, for example 16.55 would round to 16.5

"except for when the second decimal number is 5 and then it rounds it down" Because that's what you asked for; that's what the third parameter is saying to do. From the documentation: "When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated." 16.55 truncated to 1 decimal place is 16.5. Surely you just wanted ROUND(time, 1), no?

@ThomA you are totally correct, I chose the wrong option, and with your way it works! Thank you

The question is unclear. You already get what you want, rounding up on half. How those numbers are displayed is up to the application

@PanagiotisKanavos yes I chose the wrong options for the ROUND function and didn't understand why it wasn't doing the right thing. But now Thom made it clear. Too bad I can't delete the question anymore. I did vote to close though

ROUND, according to the documentation has these parameters:
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )  

so you have a numeric expression and you want to make it of a certain length by rounding it. The function is described as

Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

So, if you pass something as a third parameter, then ROUND will effectively truncate rather than round. Your call of
SELECT ROUND(time, 1, 1) as time

passes a third parameter, so you end up with a truncation. Since you wanted rounding instead, avoid passing a third parameter and call the function like this:
SELECT ROUND(time, 1) as time

